# Why am I unable to add a repository to project in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to add a new repository to my project but don't see the option. I have 5 projects and all of them I am able to, any reason why not here?

Here I see the "add" option:

[image]

But here I don't:

[image]

Comment: Do you have repositories.add RBAC permission over the scope of this project?

Answer (score 2):

Your current account does not have the permission to delete or add new repositories under your current project called **Homeazzon**.

Please enter **Homeazzon** project-->**Project Settings**-->**Repos**-->**Repositories**-->Security

check every Azure Devops Group and User and then set Create repository and Delete repository to **Allow**.

[image]